# add row with specific row class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have 2 colums and 1 add row button but i want to add row between row class "title" and "ongkir" but this my original code, but still add new row after "ongkir" pls help me

here my table

```
           <table class="table table-hover order-list">
            <tr class="title">
              <th>No</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td><input type="button" style="width: 50px;" class="btn btn-success" id="addrow" value="+"></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="ongkir">
              <td>JNE</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

here my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var counter = 2;

$("#addrow").on("click", function () {
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";
    cols += '<td>'+ counter + '</td>';
    newRow.append(cols);
    $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    counter++;
});
$("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();       
    counter -= 1
});
```

});

Comment: Don't use append then. There are other insertion methods that do what you want https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-outside/. Go through them and try alternate approaches

Comment: ok thank you for you solution hehehe -A-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `insertBefore` function instead of `append` as follow:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
var counter = 2;

$("#addrow").on("click", function () {
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";
    cols += '<td>'+ counter + '</td>';
    newRow.append(cols);
    newRow.insertBefore( "tr.ongkir" );
    counter++;
});
$("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();       
    counter -= 1
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover order-list">
            <tr class="title">
              <th>No</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td><input type="button" style="width: 50px;" class="btn btn-success" id="addrow" value="+"></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="ongkir">
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

Comment: oh thank you for fix my problem :D where i forget to delete $("table.order-list").append(newRow); after newRow.insertBefore("tr.ongkir"); sorry for my misfocus